# Training data converted to feature vectors but test data is string or text

Tags: python, nlp, random-forest, kaggle

`clean_train_reviews` is a `list` of `strings`.

Each string is a review, an example is included below:

> classic war worlds timothy hines entertaining film obviously goes
>   great effort lengths faithfully recreate h g wells classic book mr
>   hines succeeds watched film appreciated fact standard predictable
>   hollywood fare comes every year e g spielberg version tom cruise
>   slightest resemblance book obviously everyone looks different things
>   movie envision amateur critics look criticize everything others rate
>   movie important bases like entertained people never agree critics
>   enjoyed effort mr hines put faithful h g wells classic novel found
>   entertaining made easy overlook critics perceive shortcomings

Using the `vectorizer` initialized below, the above string is converted into a feature vector of the form:

> (sentence_index, feature_index) count

An example is:

> (0, 1905)     3

This means "a sentence with id of 0 and feature with id or index of 1905 occurs 3 times in this string.

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",   \
                             tokenizer = None,    \
                             preprocessor = None, \
                             stop_words = None,   \
                             max_features = 5000)
```

`train["sentiment"]` is a string of 1's and 0's (1=positive sentiment, 0=negative sentiment)

```
train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(clean_train_reviews)
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
forest = forest.fit( train_data_features, train["sentiment"] )
```

My question is:

The random forest is trained on the feature vector (all numeric values) and the sentiment (which is again numeric). But the test data set is plain text english. When the trained model is run on the test data, how does the model know what to make of plain text in the test data because the model was 
only trained on feature vectors, which were only numbers? Or does the `forest` object retain information about the plain text in the training data?

Answer (score 0):

Test data should also be converted into feature vectors using the same vectorizer (used for creating training vectors).
Only then it can serve as an input to the model.

Comment: yes, it is. But then is the word information not lost?

Comment: Information is never lost. It is just represented in a different format. Always have a mapping between vector and the word, using which you can trace back the word information